# cant initialize certain pointers, breaks program at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

Iv'e been following a tutorial line for line on binary tree's, and I'm still pretty new to template and abstract classes.

I am declaring 3 pointers to the node struct, *current, *trail and *newNode, then assigning them.

Of course, I tried setting those 3 pointers to **nullptr** upon declaration but it breaks the program on that line on runtime.

the errors I get are:

*"Potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'trail' used."*

**and**

*uninitialized local variable "newNode" used.*

The function:

```
template<class elemType>
void searchTree<elemType>::insert(const elemType& item)
{
    nodeType<elemType> *current, *trail, *newNode;
    newNode->info = item; // Cant assign, first error
    newNode->leftLink = NULL;
    newNode->rightLink = NULL;
    if (root == NULL)
        root = newNode;
    else
    {
        current = root;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            trail = current;
            if (current->info == item)
            {
                cout << "Item is already in tree, no duplicates." << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if (current->info > item)
                current = current->leftLink;
            else
                current = current->rightLink;
        }
        if (trail->info > item) // second error
            trail->leftLink = newNode;
        else
            trail->rightLink = newNode;

    }

}
```

I was already here: [Potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'node' used. C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749206/potentially-uninitialized-local-pointer-variable-node-used-c)

And I tried every suggestion including

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4703)
```

But the pointers are still uninitialized it still breaks on that line.

Any advice (or pointers) would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Do as recommended: initialize them, with `new`. `nullptr` is by definition an invalid pointer ‎address you should never dereference (e.g. here `newNode->something`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty new to pointers as well I think

```
nodeType<elemType> *current, *trail, *newNode;
```

At this point newNode has no value, it 'points' nowhere meaningful

```
newNode->info = item;
```

At this point you use the meaningless value of newNode. This is what your compiler is warning about.

What you need to do is something like this

```
nodeType<elemType> *current, *trail, *newNode;
newNode = new nodeType<elemType>(); // make newNode point at a new node
newNode->info = item;
newNode->leftLink = NULL;
newNode->rightLink = NULL;
```

The second warning is bogus. The compiler is worried that you will never execute the body of the while loop, and so trail may not be initialised. But the way you have written the code the while loop will always be executed at least once. To remove the warning you could rewrite your while loop as a do ... while loop.

```
    do
    {
        trail = current;
        if (current->info == item)
        {
            cout << "Item is already in tree, no duplicates." << endl;
            return;
        }
        else if (current->info > item)
            current = current->leftLink;
        else
            current = current->rightLink;
    }
    while (current != NULL);
```

That way the compiler will know that trail is being initialised.

Comment: Your darn right I am, but I think I just had a pointer breakthrough because of you. The code works perfectly now so your the best. Its just funny how the code worked fine for the guy in the tutorial I'm following.